# Solaris linker equivalent to the GNU LD --export-dynamic flag

Tags: linker, solaris, shared-libraries, ld

Like the question says:  We are building on Linux using the GNU linker, and on Solaris using the solaris `ld`.  GNU `ld` supports the `--export-dynamic` flag, which:

> When creating a dynamically linked executable, add all symbols to the dynamic 
>   symbol table.  The dynamic symbol table is the set of symbols which are visible 
>   from dynamic objects at run time.

What is the equivalent to this flag using the solaris linker?  *Is* there an equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sun Studio linker (`ld`), by default, exports all symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete reference for the Sun linker on docs.sun.com.
Search for the "Linker and Libraries Guide".
By "all symbols" you mean all global symbols, right?  C file-static symbols
are not promoted to global right?  I don't think that would work.