# Is there any difference between -Xlinker -export-dynamic and -rdynamic?

Tags: c++, g++, gnu, ld

This is a pretty straight forward question. Is there **any** difference between:

> -Xlinker --export-dynamic

and

> -rdynamic

when passed to g++? Reading the GNU documentation it seems they are functionally identical but I'd like to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a pretty straight forward question. Is there any difference between: `-Xlinker -export-dynamic` and `-rdynamic`

It depends.

If you are using GNU-ld (or gold) as your linker, then `-Xlinker --export-dynamic` (note: you have a missing dash in your question) is exactly equivalent to `-rdynamic`.

But on e.g. Solaris, `-rdynamic` will do the right thing and pass nothing to the linker (Sun `ld` apparently [exports all symbols by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596076/solaris-linker-equivalent-to-the-gnu-ld-export-dynamic-flag)), while the `-Xlinker ...` variant will result in a [link error](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=121054).

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on what you mean by doing the right thing? Are you meaning that -rdynamic should in fact remove the symbols? But in GNU-ld since it defaults to not exporting the symbols it chooses to do the opposite?

Comment: Do the right thing == pass whatever flag is necessary to the underlying linker to export symbols. That flag could be `--export-dynamic` when the underlying linker is a gnu-ld, or some other flag for a different system linker, or no flag at all (if none is required, e.g. in case of Solaris).